# ffmpeg complex filter - multiple crops on black background

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

We are attempting to process a video file by cropping it into several pieces and arranging it on a black background which is exactly 1920x1080. The following command runs but it never completes and we have to kill the process.

Is there something wrong with how we're trying to do this?

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -y -filter_complex "\
color=s=1920x1080:c=black[bg];\
[0:v]crop=w=1920:h=ih:x=0:y=0[crop1];\
[0:v]crop=w=iw-1920:h=ih:x=1920:y=0[crop2];\
[bg][crop1]overlay=x=0:y=0[out1];\
[out1][crop2]overlay=x=0:y=h[final]" \
-map [final] out.mov
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `color` base has no duration set, and so runs indefinitely. The overlay filter by default terminates when the longer input ends. Here, it doesn't. So, let's correct that.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -y -filter_complex "\
color=s=1920x1080:c=black[bg];\
[0:v]crop=w=1920:h=ih:x=0:y=0[crop1];\
[0:v]crop=w=iw-1920:h=ih:x=1920:y=0[crop2];\
[bg][crop1]overlay=x=0:y=0:shortest=1[out1];\
[out1][crop2]overlay=x=0:y=h[final]" \
-map [final] out.mov
```

Comment: One other question, any idea why we're seeing such a loss in quality in the output file?

Comment: ffprobe says the input codec is qtrle and the output codec is h264

Comment: Share the full console log.